# Cannot get response from axios

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, axios

I am trying to make an axios call to post a blog and return a response message, if the response is `"success"`, then it should continue, for testing purposes I am just doing `console.log("success ok")`, the problem is, I ran into a strange issue I cannot understand.

Here is my function `publishBlog`:

```
const publishBlog = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log('ready to publishBlog');

    const response = createBlog(blogInfo, token)

    console.log(`my response: ${JSON.stringify(response)}`);

    //should be if(response.data.message) {
    if (response === "success") { 
        console.log("success ok")
    }
}
```

The method `createBlog` is here:

```
export const createBlog = (blog, token) => {
    console.log(`body: ${JSON.stringify(blog)}, token: ${token}`)

    const [username, role] = isAuth();

    console.log(`isAuth resp: ${username}`)
    console.log(`isAuth role resp: ${role}`)

    let createBlogEndPoint;

    if (username && role === 1) {
        console.log('role equals 1')
        createBlogEndPoint = '/blog'
    } else if (username && role === 0) {
        console.log('role equals 0')
        createBlogEndPoint = '/user/blog'
    }

    const blogInfo = { title: blog.title, body: blog.body, postedByUserName: username }

    return axios.post(axios.defaults.baseURL + createBlogEndPoint, blogInfo)
    .then(response => {
        console.log(`axios data: ${JSON.stringify(response)}`)
        console.log(`axios message: ${JSON.stringify(response.data.message)}`)


        return response;
    })//.catch(err => console.log(err));

};
```

Here is my problem:

looks like this line of code:

```
console.log(`my response: ${JSON.stringify(response)}`);
```

ran before this line of code:

```
const response = createBlog(blogInfo, token)
```

When you look at the console log, this is what I mean:

[image]

How could I be able to check if `response` is ok? I am trying to return the axios response, and then check `if (response.data.message == "success")`, so I could continue.

Comment: Would it be valid to say `const response = await createBlog(blogInfo, token)` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is happening because your `createBlog` is returning a `Promise`, so you should change your code to use `async/await` to solve it.

I am not 100% aware of your code, so try this:

```js
const publishBlog = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log('ready to publishBlog');

    const response = await createBlog(blogInfo, token)

    console.log(`my response: ${JSON.stringify(response)}`);

    //should be if(response.data.message) {
    if (response === "success") { 
        console.log("success ok")
    }
}
```

Comment: why did this get a negative? `async/await` worked for me. Well I learned something new.

Comment: No idea, I was thinking the same... @AlejandroH remember that `return axios.something` is always a `Promise`, so you have to take care (where you then use it) to handle it. Remember to mark it as solved.

Comment: I need to learn about this `Promise`, I will look it up.

Comment: No worries at all, sorry for not sharing a link to a site explaining it, I am helping a lot of people here so I try to give best answer and continue. You can [read this](https://www.loginradius.com/blog/async/callback-vs-promises-vs-async-await/), it looks okay ! Also have a look at the [axios documentation](https://github.com/axios/axios)